# parallel execution in selenium without using testng

Tags: java, selenium

Till now I am running multiple scripts in parallel in selenium using `testNG` framework. 
Now I have to run these scripts in parallel using only java with out using any framework. 
Is there any possible way?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You have to do is to set Global env. variable "ClassPath", in which you have to mention path of all classes(Selenium Jars and other classes also if used) which is used in Selenium Script.
Then you can run multiple Selenium Scripts from CMD at same time and to make process easy you can also create BAT files. You can also schedule Selenium Script with BAT files.

Hope my answer will help you.
Thank You,
Ed D, India.